# How AWS Auto Scaling Group shows 33GiB for m5.2xlarge?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-asg

As per this document,

> https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/

m5.2xlarge will have 8 vCPUs and 32GB Memory.

But, when I create Auto Scaling Group and select m5.2xlarge as the instance type I see 33GiB in the Memory field.

How does ASG shows 33GiB?

Go to EC2 --> Auto Scaling Groups --> Select the ASG --> Purchase options and instance types

[image]

Comment: When I create a Launch Configuration and select `m5.2xlarge`, it shows Memory as 32. Can you clarify where you are seeing 33GiB?

Comment: sorry to respond late, but I added the screenshot where it shows 33gb

Comment: Mmm, sounds like a UI problem. Feel free to report it to AWS by clicking the "Feedback" button at the bottom of the page that shows the incorrect value.